# Building a React Circular Progress Bar with Gap Between Progress and Track

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I am trying to build a Circular Progress Bar Component with gaps between progress and track parts like this:

[image: Design]

I know how to build a normal circular progress bar, but I'm not sure how can I approach it to make it have gaps between the progress and track parts.

Can anyone lead me in the proper direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem statement you are describing is better known as `Segmented Progress Bar` it would be a `segmented circular progress bar` in this case.

A good approach to solving this is using `SVG` based approach which gives some flexibility over the implementation.

With this implementation, the key to creating the segments is specifying "offsets" within the `stroke-dasharray`.

For example, `stroke-dasharray='25 5'` would create a pattern where the fill is 25px and then a 5px spacing creating segments in the fill.

You may refer to the following links for more clarity.

- https://codepen.io/esprimo/pen/MjyYBK
- https://nikitahl.com/svg-circle-progress

Using the above references, I have created a version of react implementation that fits the diagram that you have added in the question where only the background looks to be segmented and the progress bar is covering as per usual based on the percentage. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-z9eklg

In case the requirement is that you have to cover a complete segment and not partial, then you may see this implementation.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-che2tk

Also with SVG it always takes a bit of trial and error to get what you need. I am no expert either :)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the amazing response. Moving forward with your codebase, I was able to dynamically construct the dash array to exactly meet my needs. Sharing the final code here: https://codefile.io/f/E3RIryoBoL. Cheers!

Comment: @ÜmitAparı Happy that my answer helped! Also thanks for sharing the final version as well, it looks super cool with the dynamic approach :)